# Comparing 2 folders and saving the paths into a variable?

Tags: powershell, compare, get-childitem

I've been given the task of comparing 2 folders, FolderA and FolderB and noting any files that exist in A but not in B.

Sorry for not explaining myself fully.  Maybe it would help if I explain our situation.   A company sales employee has left our company to go to a competitor. He has files in on his work laptop local hard drive.  We are trying to establish if there are any files that exist on his computer but not on the shared network folder.

I need to produce a list of any files (along with their paths) that are present on his laptop but not on the share network location.  The file structure between the laptop local hard drive and the shared network location are different.   What's the best way to go about this?

```
$folderAcontent = "C:\temp\test1" 
$folderBcontent = "C:\temp\test2"

$FolderAContents = Get-ChildItem $folderAcontent -Recurse | where-object {!$_.PSIsContainer}
$FolderBContents = Get-ChildItem $folderBcontent -Recurse | where-object {!$_.PSIsContainer}

$FolderList = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($FolderAContents ) -DifferenceObject ($FolderBContents) -Property name
$FolderList | fl *
```

Comment: just comparing filenames (ex. test.txt) or the files content? does the files have unique filenames or are they stored in a subfolder with identical names? how do we know if they're are a match?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself fully.  I've updated the question with more information. Just file names and thinking about it size, no need to compare contents unless this is easier to do this.  Its only file names i'm interested in comparing as the location between the 2 sets of folders have different structures.  they are a match if file name and size are the same.

Comment: I changed my answer now to account for filesize. My old and the other answers here only compares filenames.

Answer (score 5):

Use the compare-Object cmdlet :

```
Compare-Object (gci $folderAcontent) (gci $folderBcontent)
```

if you want to list  the file that are only in $folderAcontent select the results with the <= SideIndicator :

```
Compare-Object (gci $folderAcontent) (gci $folderBcontent) | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do what he wants, except you need to add the `-Recurse` switch so it will get all the files in the sub-folders (shown in his question)

Comment: also, he wants the path to the missing files. so extend it with something like `| % { $_.inputobject.fullname }`

Comment: btw. will this work if the same filename is in different subfolders? doesn't it just compare the toString() value(filename only) of the files?

Comment: The question sounds like he is looking for specifics directory structure, but if all he wants to check just by name, changing it to `(Get-ChildItems $folderAcontent -recursive | Select name)` and would compare only the files names directly

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself fully.  I've updated the question with more information.  I've used the compare-object which tells me the files names that don't match. However, it doesnt tell me the file paths? I need to produce a list of any files (along with their paths) that are present on his laptop but not on the share network location. The file structure between the laptop local hard drive and the shared network location are different.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that the filenames in both the directories are same, you can do something like the following :-

```
$folderAcontent = "C:\temp\test1"  
$folderBcontent = "C:\temp\test2"

ForEach($File in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $FolderA | where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} | Select-Object Name)
{
   if(!(Test-Path "$folderBcontent\$File"))
{
   write-host "Missing File: $folderBcontent\$File"
}
}
```

The above will only work for files (not subdirectories) present in folder A

Comment: That code shouldn't work. 1st. your `$file` variable is not defined anywhere. 2nd. it won't work with subfolders under foldera or folderb.

Comment: Sorry. I had actually edited the code but forgot to do it correctly. Let me correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#Set locations
$laptopfolder = "c:\test1"
$serverfolder = "c:\test2"

#Get contents
$laptopcontents = Get-ChildItem $laptopfolder -Recurse | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}
$servercontents = Get-ChildItem $serverfolder -Recurse | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}

#Compare on name and length and find changed files on laptop
$diff = Compare-Object $laptopcontents $servercontents -Property name, length -PassThru | where {$_.sideindicator -eq "<="}

#Output differences
$diff | Select-Object FullName
```

If you add `lastwritetime` after length in the compare-object cmdlet it will compare modified date too(if the file was updated but still same size). Just be aware that it only looks for differnt dates, not if it's newer or older. :)